# R bind_rows() error: Argument 1 must have names

Tags: r

I have 3 dataframes. Every df has 3 A-variables and 3 B-variables and 3 thresholds (1, 2, 3)

```
df1 <- tibble(
var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)


df2 <- tibble(
var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)


df3 <- tibble(
var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)

thresholds = c(1, 2, 3)
list_dfs = c('df1','df2','df3')
```

Now I want to perform a t.test for all A- and B-variables and for all dfs (for examle t.test df1$var1A and df1$var1B). I will perform the t.test with the help of `matrixTests::col_t_welch()`

```
map(list_dfs,
function(df_name){
  x <- get(df_name)
  lapply(thresholds, function(i){

    col_t_welch(x %>%
             pull(paste0("var",i,"A")), 
           x %>% 
             pull(paste0("var",i,"B")))

  }) 
})
```

And now I geht for every threshold and every df a table of the t.test of varA and varB.

Finally I want to bind all these tables with bind_rows(). But then I get an error message:Argument 1 must have names

```
map(list_dfs,
function(df_name){
  x <- get(df_name)
  lapply(thresholds, function(i){

    col_t_welch(x %>%
             pull(paste0("var",i,"A")), 
           x %>% 
             pull(paste0("var",i,"B")))

  }) 
}) %>% bind_rows

Error: Argument 1 must have names
```

Can someone help me how can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the result you want?

First, I load the libraries and create the data, as per your question.

```r
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(matrixTests)

df1 <- tibble(
  var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
  var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
  var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
  var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
  var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
  var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)


df2 <- tibble(
  var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
  var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
  var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
  var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
  var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
  var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)


df3 <- tibble(
  var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
  var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
  var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
  var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
  var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
  var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)

thresholds = c(1, 2, 3)
list_dfs = c('df1','df2','df3')
```

Here, I `unlist` the results before binding.

```r
map(list_dfs,
    function(df_name){
      x <- get(df_name)
      lapply(thresholds, function(i){

        col_t_welch(x %>%
                      pull(paste0("var",i,"A")), 
                    x %>% 
                      pull(paste0("var",i,"B")))

      }) 
    }) %>% 
  unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

which gives,

```r
#>   obs.x obs.y obs.tot    mean.x    mean.y   mean.diff     var.x     var.y
#> 1    10    10      20 0.4123358 0.9386079 -0.52627205 1.2887733 1.4188697
#> 2    10    10      20 1.4848642 1.8852731 -0.40040891 0.7594906 1.9971866
#> 3    10    10      20 2.9905342 3.1454473 -0.15491307 0.9501264 0.6863846
#> 4    10    10      20 1.2409187 0.9453490  0.29556964 1.8969049 0.5213807
#> 5    10    10      20 2.0823664 2.3150223 -0.23265591 0.5171046 0.6771720
#> 6    10    10      20 3.0354769 2.2958400  0.73963696 0.8915344 1.1509940
#> 7    10    10      20 0.5546491 0.8868825 -0.33223340 0.6404670 0.4313640
#> 8    10    10      20 2.9031533 2.5956085  0.30754479 1.1602239 1.6080605
#> 9    10    10      20 3.1435888 3.1988889 -0.05530018 1.7926813 0.4374122
#>      stderr       df  statistic    pvalue   conf.low conf.high alternative
#> 1 0.5203502 17.95854 -1.0113806 0.3252679 -1.6196681 0.5671240   two.sided
#> 2 0.5250407 14.98023 -0.7626246 0.4575287 -1.5196353 0.7188175   two.sided
#> 3 0.4045381 17.54432 -0.3829381 0.7063657 -1.0064012 0.6965751   two.sided
#> 4 0.4917607 13.59994  0.6010437 0.5576963 -0.7620703 1.3532096   two.sided
#> 5 0.3455831 17.68236 -0.6732272 0.5095070 -0.9596350 0.4943232   two.sided
#> 6 0.4519434 17.71416  1.6365699 0.1193625 -0.2109603 1.6902343   two.sided
#> 7 0.3273883 17.34004 -1.0147992 0.3241530 -1.0219320 0.3574652   two.sided
#> 8 0.5261449 17.54094  0.5845249 0.5663102 -0.7999219 1.4150114   two.sided
#> 9 0.4722387 13.14519 -0.1171022 0.9085494 -1.0743655 0.9637651   two.sided
#>   mean.null conf.level
#> 1         0       0.95
#> 2         0       0.95
#> 3         0       0.95
#> 4         0       0.95
#> 5         0       0.95
#> 6         0       0.95
#> 7         0       0.95
#> 8         0       0.95
#> 9         0       0.95
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Could also use `map_df(bind_rows)` instead of unlisting.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different data types of database then you can bring those into same format with help of data.frame. Ex. if one database is list type and other is double type or vice versa and you would like to combine both then first convert both in data.frame and use cbind to use two dataframe.

combine_data <- cbind(data.frame(data_r), data.frame(data_c))